# Getting success responce but alert error dialog box

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

I'm writing a function in WordPress for send an email by using Mailer. After `add_action()` I'm writing a function and require a file `pluggable.php`. I guess I'm including it in a wrong way or I have to include it some other way. If it didn't give any error its not print the `print_r($phpmailer)`. Please help me out Thanks in advance.

Here is my function with the hook

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'New_Mail');

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function New_Mail($phpmailer){

echo  require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../wp-includes/pluggable.php';

print_r($phpmailer);

die();

}
```

I have tried many solutions `do_action_ref_array()`, `get_home_url()` and `($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])`.

Comment: If you are writing a WordPress plugin or just a custom code in functions.php, no need to include `pluggable.php` again.

Comment: But codex says something else [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/phpmailer_init)

Comment: No, just use their example code, no need to re-include pluggable.php file. By the way, your `require_once` is wrong with echo.